# How to know when the user clicks a target="_blank" link in WebView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, macos

I want to track users clicking links in a WebView and then open that link in Safari. I used **decidePolicyForNewWindowAction** method in **WebPolicyDelegate** but when the link is a

```
<a href="" target="_blank">
```

type of link which should be opened in a new window, the delegate method is not called.

How can I know when a user click the target="_blank" link?

Answer (score 0):

hi you can capture link clicked event in UIWebview

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType 
{
if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
   //you can open the link within Safari here...
    return NO;
}
return YES;
}
```

thanks.

Comment: He is asking about WebView not UIWebview.